# VMWare daemon doesn't startup when system starts

Tags: debian, init-script, init.d

I have installed VMware Player on my Debian squueze, but after the reboot the vmware daemon(`/etc/init.d/vmware`) does not start up automatically, i have tried without any success to set the daemon startup with insserv :

```
insserv vmware
```

but it gives me the following output :

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnclient_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2) of script `vmware' overwrites defaults (2 3 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 3 5 6) of script `vmware' overwrites defaults (2 3 5).
insserv: warning: script 'vpnclient_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script vboxdrv: service vboxdrv already provided!
```

and it doesn't work ... Why ?
How can i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSB tags are the "Linux Standard Base" script headers that tell `insserv` and `chkconfig` how to create the companion `rc.?` scripts. You have to create a LSB header and re-run `insserv`

**Edit:**

Rather after actually taking the time to look at all your information it may have the LSB header but not configured correctly. Search for `LSB init scripts` and there are several links out there. You have to either configure the LSB header better or differently, or you have to add additional information like the `source` of the LSB functions.

Also, it looks like the header might have been configured for RH or SUSE based distros given that it is starting in 2,3,5. You have some conflicting settings listed in your `insserv` line.

**Edit 2:**

If you don't mind could you put the first 20 or so lines of the `/etc/init.d/vmware` init script into your question. Thanks

**Edit 3: Links**

[Debian Wiki: How to LSBize an Init Script](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)

[The Geek Stuff: How to Write Linux Init Scripts Based on LSB Init Standard](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/)